# Execute local (bash|python) script with mysql SQL

Tags: linux, mysql, bash, python

I want to create a trigger so that when a field is updated it kicks off a local bash script (or python...whatever) to kick off a workflow (emails, work requests, etc). Is it possible to execute local system scripts/executables from mysql SQL?  My google searches have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Check this stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1467387/531201

Answer (score 0):

It seems not easy to do it. I think it will be better to do it at the application level if at all possible. You can also query your table for updated rows every x minutes and then execute the script in a cron job.

Comment: To recognize the updated rows easily, you can add a new column `updated` that should be set to 1 to indicate the updated rows. A trigger after update will set this flag to 1 and your script will clear it.

Comment: Just default the column to 1 instead of abusing a trigger for this.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, a once-per-minute cron job that queries a table with pending tasks is the better solution here.

You won't be calling potentially privileged OS code from a database server, and the control over task execution remains firmly in the hands of your application(s).